# indexing a list with a tensor scalar variable in theano

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano, theano.scan

I have a  list :

```
my_list = [[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6], [1,2,1,2,1,2]]
```

I also have a tensor variable:

```
a_tensor = theano.tensor.ivector("tensor")
```

now I want to use theano.scan to get the corresponding item in the list given the index:

```
result, _ = theano.scan(fn=lambda idx, a_list:a_list[idx],
                        sequences=[a_tensor], 
                        non_sequences=theano.shared(np.array(my_list)))
```

but got the error:
*TypeError: The generic 'SharedVariable' object is not subscriptable. This shared variable contains a Numpy array with dtype: 'object'. This data type is not currently recognized by Theano tensors: please cast your data into a supported numeric type if you need Theano tensor functionalities.
*

I'm very new to Theano so I'm probably thinking about this problem in the wrong way. I would really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

In the error message,

> TypeError: The generic 'SharedVariable' object is not subscriptable. This shared variable contains a Numpy array with **dtype: 'object'**. This data type is not currently recognized by Theano tensors: please cast your data into a supported numeric type if you need Theano tensor functionalities.

The shared variable passed to `theano.scan` as `non_sequences` is not properly defined. This is because `np.array(my_list)` returns a array of which dtype is **object**, not integer. That's because `my_list` has irregular shape.

With

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
```

, your code would work.